# Muliple Pushpins in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, bing-maps

I am using MapControl to display map. I have MapServiceToken too. I have added custom pushpin using MapIcon and assigned this object to Map. It is working fine.
But when i try to add multiple pushpins using same scenario and assign it to map so i am getting last pushpin on the map. Rest of other pushpins are not getting visible.
Kindly tell me any simple solution to this problem. Thanks

Comment: I am really stucked at this point. Please help me

Answer (score 2):

You can binding your pushpins on map without MapIcon.

Add in xaml

```
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="MapLocationsControl" MapServiceToken="add your token here">
        <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapitem">
            <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                        <Image Height="50" Width="50"
                               Source="{Binding image,Mode=OneWay}"
                       Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Geopoint}"/>

                </DataTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl>
    </Maps:MapControl>
```

And in c# binding items in MapControl source

```
 mapitem.ItemsSource = items;
```

Where items is observable collection with MapItems class items. You can add items with Add().

```
ObservableCollection<MapItem> items = new ObservableCollection<MapItem>();

items.Add(new MapItem(lat,lng, "Assets/pushpinicon.png"));
```

MapItem Class is like this

```
public class MapItem {

public Geopoint Geopoint { get; set; }

public string image {get; set;}

    public MapItem(double lat , double lng , string img)
    {

        Geopoint = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = lat, Longitude = lng });

        image=img;
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the `Source="{Binding image,Mode=OneWay}"` image refering too?

Comment: I edit me code and add image property . This image is your pushpin icon where you want .

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: if my code give you solution, please mark up as answered and useful ! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Evilunclebill,, your answers works for me too, Please upvote my devoted question although it was very logical.