# Windows Phone 8.1 binding bing map pushpins

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I want to display pushpins based on my ObservableCollection:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <my:MapControl>
        <my:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
            <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <my:MapIcon  Title="{Binding Name}" Location="{Binding Location}"></my:MapIcon>
                </DataTemplate>
            </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </my:MapItemsControl>
    </my:MapControl>
</Grid>
```

Here ViewModel:
public ObservableCollection Users { get; set; }

```
public MapPageViewModel()
{
    Users = new ObservableCollection<User>()
    {
        new User
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Chris",
            Location = new Location { Latitude = 52.645, Longitude = 13.431}
        },
        new User
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Brown",
            Location = new Location { Latitude = 52.15, Longitude = 12.431}
        }
    };
}
```

There is error while trying to display map icons when starting program anyway there is error in line

> Title={Binding Name}

It cannot resolve Name even if User model has property Name and I set ItemSource to Users.

Does anyone have idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your xaml

```
<Grid>
    <my:MapControl>
        <my:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Hairdressers}">
            <my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <my:MapIcon  Title="{Binding Name}" Location="{Binding Location}"></my:MapIcon>
                </DataTemplate>
            </my:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </my:MapItemsControl>
    </my:MapControl>
</Grid>
```

Specify Your Observable Collection name i.e. **Hairdressers** instead of Users because your collection name is **Hairdressers** :

```
public ObservableCollection Hairdressers { get; set; }
```

Comment: its my misteke writning here in my code its still Users and doesnt work :(

Comment: Ok.Then take a look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471206/muliple-pushpins-in-windows-phone-8-1.This will surely help you.